# Image "carousel" animation in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm recreating an Objective-C app in SwiftUI. In my old app, I have a full-screen background image that has a slide transition between several images. Here's the Objective-C code:

```objective-c
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.output.text = [self.output.text stringByAppendingString:@"viewWillAppear\r\n"];

    [self resetCardReader];

    self.creditCard = [[FWCCreditCard alloc] init];

    _imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Family on Beach.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Chinese Graduate.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"New Car.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"House Sold.png"], nil];

    index = 0;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.slideTransition = [CATransition animation]; // CATransition * slideTransition; instance variable
    self.slideTransition.duration = 2.0;
    self.slideTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    self.slideTransition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    self.slideTransition.delegate = self;
    self.slideTransition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight; // or kCATransitionFromLeft

    self.repeatingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(slideShow) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self.repeatingTimer fire];

}

-(void)slideShow
{
    [self.BackgroundImage.layer addAnimation:self.slideTransition forKey:nil];

    if (index < self.imageArray.count-1) // NSUInteger  index; instance variable
    {
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        index=0;
    }
    self.BackgroundImage.image =[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Here's what I have so far in SwiftUI. Can anyone give me some pointers on where to add the animation?

```swiftui
struct HomeView : View {

    private var backgroundImages = ["Family on Beach","Chinese Graduate","New Car","House Sold"]
    private var backgroundImageIndex = 0

    @State private var backgroundImage = "Family on Beach"

    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            Image(backgroundImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .colorMultiply(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.286, blue: 0.486, opacity: 0.8))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .statusBar(hidden: true)
```

Comment: Can you paste in the rest of your `HomeView` implementation? It cuts off about half way through :)

Comment: Just close the ZStack, body View and HomeView View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got it:

```swiftui
import SwiftUI

extension AnyTransition {
    static var rightToLeft: AnyTransition {
        let insertion = AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)
        let removal = AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading)
        return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
    }
}

struct HomeView : View {

    private var backgroundImages = ["Family on Beach","Chinese Graduate","New Car","House Sold"]
    @State private var backgroundImageIndex = 0
    @State private var backgroundImageNameEven = "Family on Beach"
    @State private var backgroundImageNameOdd = "Chinese Graduate"
    @State private var showImage = true

    var timer: Timer {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true){_ in
            if(self.backgroundImageIndex < self.backgroundImages.count-1){
                self.backgroundImageIndex += 1
            } else
            {
                self.backgroundImageIndex = 0
            }
            if(self.backgroundImageIndex % 2 == 0){
                self.backgroundImageNameEven = self.backgroundImages[self.backgroundImageIndex]
            } else {
                self.backgroundImageNameOdd = self.backgroundImages[self.backgroundImageIndex]
            }
            withAnimation{
                self.showImage.toggle()
            }
        }
    }

    var OddImage: some View {
        Image(backgroundImageNameOdd)
            .resizable()
            .clipped()
            .colorMultiply(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.286, blue: 0.486, opacity: 0.8))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .animation(.basic(duration: 2))
            .transition(.rightToLeft)
    }

    var EvenImage: some View {
            Image(backgroundImageNameEven)
                .resizable()
                .clipped()
                .colorMultiply(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.286, blue: 0.486, opacity: 0.8))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .animation(.basic(duration: 2))
                .transition(.rightToLeft)
    }

    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            if(!self.showImage){
                OddImage
            }
            if(self.showImage){
                EvenImage
            }
```

Just add the following to any other element on the view to trigger the timer on view:

```swiftui
.onAppear(perform: {
    let _ = self.timer
})
```